# Class structure for future multi-threading

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, data-structures, concurrency

I have an algorithm that runs on a large problem set. It reads the problem instance, 
then runs the algorithm on that problem read from the file.

The solution space can be partitioned (can be split into disjoint sets that cover the entire space).
That is, the algorithm can take advantage of concurrency/multi-threading.

It isn't doing any concurrent processing at the moment. 
However, for the latter enhancements, i'm trying to make the class structured for this.

One thing i'm doing is:

keeping the field members & methods that read the problem, and have no affect or are affected by the solution instances as `static`

&

the rest of the members-- the field variables specific to each solution space & methods that run on solution spaces as `non-static`.

Is the anything more I should do for future concurrency at this point?

TIA.

Comment: If the solution can be split into disjoint sets wouldn't it be better to use fork-join providing you are on Java >= 7

Comment: @sol4me it probably is. wont get into any concurrency for now-- time not allowing. but looking to put it into the right "shape" while at it.

Comment: Fork-join _is_ a "right shape".

Answer (score 0):

Structure the problem file such that you can immediately start processing sub-problems, as opposed to structuring the file such that you'll need to read in the entire file before you can start to work on it.  For example, using **|** as the separating character, the file would look like

```
[size_of_subproblem_header]|[size_of_subproblem_0]|[size_of_subproblem_1]|...|[subproblem_0]|[subproblem_1]|...
```

Then you can use something like a `BufferedReader` to read in the size of the subproblem header, then use **read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)** to read in each individual subproblem and send it off to a worker queue where it will be parsed and processed, without needing to wait for the entire problem to be read + parsed